# Bootstrap button & loading animation

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, button, margin, padding

I've added loading animation to the bootstrap button, and it is not showing correctly.

I've added a div to the button with the class "loader". But the loading animation is showing under the button.

How can I fix it with responsive design

Here is codepen: https://codepen.io/ayxano/pen/oNNxgQx

```
.loader,
.loader:before,
.loader:after {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 2.5em;
  height: 2.5em;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation: load7 1.8s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation: load7 1.8s infinite ease-in-out;
}
.loader {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 10px;
  position: relative;
  text-indent: -9999em;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.16s;
  animation-delay: -0.16s;
}
.loader:before,
.loader:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.loader:before {
  left: -3.5em;
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.32s;
  animation-delay: -0.32s;
}
.loader:after {
  left: 3.5em;
}
@-webkit-keyframes load7 {
  0%,
  80%,
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 2.5em 0 -1.3em;
  }
  40% {
    box-shadow: 0 2.5em 0 0;
  }
}
@keyframes load7 {
  0%,
  80%,
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 2.5em 0 -1.3em;
  }
  40% {
    box-shadow: 0 2.5em 0 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the box-shadow. You are using a y-offset of 2.5em.

Try below CSS in this particular case:

```
.center-block.loader {
    top: -2.5em;
}
```